# angular_1.default.module Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp, webpack

I am creating a starter template using angular 1.6, webpack, gulp and typescript. I am able to compile and build my application but app is not bootstrapping. The issue is weird as when I am debugging `angular.module` is defined and module can be created from console `angular.module('testModule', [])` but as resume debugger I get exception in `core.module.ts` at `export const CoreModule = angular.module('app.core', []).name;`.

I have further investigated this issue by disabling source code and I have found the problem. The above mentioned code compiles to `exports.CoreModule = angular_1.default.module('app.core', []).name;` where there is no property named `default` on angular_1.
For code refer https://github.com/muditsaurabh/awesome-ng-starter

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at e (vendor.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at e (vendor.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at e (vendor.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1)
    at app.bundle.js?cd4d443…:1
vendor.bundle.js?cd4d443…:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:377
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:11230
    at n (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:10668)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:11004
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:20796
    at r (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:809)
    at h (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:20644)
    at le (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:22631)
    at a (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8560)
    at st (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8870)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3Fcd4d4432605c6f5be56a%3A6%3A8870)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:377
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:11230
    at n (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:10668)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:11004
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:20796
    at r (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:809)
    at h (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:20644)
    at le (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:22631)
    at a (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8560)
    at st (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8870)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3Fcd4d4432605c6f5be56a%3A6%3A8870)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:377
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:21073
    at r (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:809)
    at h (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:20644)
    at le (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:22631)
    at a (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8560)
    at st (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8870)
    at at (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:8109)
    at http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:11:13916
    at HTMLDocument.n (http://localhost:8000/vendor.bundle.js?cd4d4432605c6f5be56a:6:17809)
```

Comment: We'll need more info, how does your webpack.config and your entry file look like?

Comment: @Dieterg I have added git repo link please clone it to see code

Comment: @Dieterg I have further investigated this issue by disabling source map and I have found the problem. The above mentioned code compiles to exports.CoreModule = angular_1.default.module('app.core', []).name; where there is no property named default on angular_1

Answer (score 5):

I have replaced `import angular from 'angular'` with `import * as angular from 'angular'` and now it is working fine.

Comment: But why is this necessary? I see a index.js file in `node_modules/angular` that sets the default export to 'angular' (this v 1.6)

Comment: Magic fix for changing JS to TS in webpack 2.X.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that AngularJS gets included before your script? The error means that the object angular hasn't been seen by Javascript yet and therefore module cannot be called on it.

Comment: I am able to get angular object from console but as I step over `export const CoreModule = angular.module('app.core', []).name;` line the code I get the exception. I think that this error is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just add

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

to your `tsconfig.json` instead of using a star import everywhere.